# Choosing Arguments with GNU Make

Tags: makefile, automake

Consider this short Makefile:

```
ARGS       := -foo
my_ARGS    := -bar
their_ARGS :=

all: your.foo my.foo their.foo

%.foo:
    @echo $*: $(call _choose_,ARGS,$*)

_isndef_ = $(findstring undefined,$(origin $1))
_choose_ = $(value $(if $(call _isndef_,$2_$1),$1,$2_$1))
```

It correctly outputs:

```
your: -foo
my: -bar
their:
```

My Questions:

- is this the way that [automake](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Linking.html) does it? (`LDADD` and `rmt_LDADD`)
- is there a shorter or better way of doing this?

Comment: I think your second question is more apt for [softwareengineering.stackexchange.com](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) as it circles around central questions (without clear answers) in configuration management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use variable name construction?  It would be just simply:

```
ARGS       := -foo
my_ARGS    := -bar
their_ARGS :=

all: your.foo my.foo their.foo

%.foo:
        @echo $*: $(or $($*_ARGS),$(ARGS))
```

More info here for example: http://make.mad-scientist.net/constructed-macro-names/

If you want to "override with empty" you can use [target-specific variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html):

```
ARGS := -foo

my.foo:    ARGS := -bar
their.foo: ARGS :=

all: your.foo my.foo their.foo

%.foo:
        @echo $*: $(ARGS)
```

Comment: If I'm right your version will produce `their: -foo` on the last line as its args will expand to the empty string - hence the definition check

Comment: Very nice, I hadn't thought of using target specific variables on a concrete instance of the pattern rule - begs the question of why the LDADD variable doesn't work like that?

Comment: You mean in automake?  Because automake generates POSIX-conforming makefiles that will work with any make, but target-specific variables, at least using this syntax, are specific to GNU make.

Comment: I did, yes - that was what I was trying to emulate. I'll have to have a read through your blog, looks like some good stuff in there. Thanks again.

Comment: Neither your solution nor mine are portable: you didn't suggest you wanted a non-GNU make portable option and since your solution was GNU make specific I didn't try to be portable.  I'm fairly confident that automake makefiles _do not_ work as you suggest, where `<prog>_LDADD` _replaces_ `LDADD`.  Instead, I think automake just uses: `$($@_LDADD) $(LDADD)`, where _both_ values are used.  `LDADD` is reserved for the user to set on the command line and so it's always empty (by default).  This is portable to POSIX make.

Comment: In my question's link the example Makefile has this supporting text _"...in GNU cpio, pax, cpio and mt are linked against the library libcpio.a. However, rmt is built in the same directory, and has no such link requirement..."_ so I think the empty version replaces the default there. I'm sure once my foo becomes stronger I'll start noticing the portability issues.